# How to relate entities - users with multiple roles

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, relationship, table-relationships

I have 3 entities to represent `Users`, `Roles` and `Conferences`
So far I got this diagram:
[image: Entities]

So,

-A user can be associated with zero or more conferences.

-A conference may have one or more users.

and...

-The same user can have different roles depending on which conference he is.

but...

**-How can I improve the diagram so i can see the different roles of a user in all the conferences he has attended?**

**[UPDATE]**

[image: NEW DIAGRAM]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like users belong to roles, and then the combination of userRoles belongs to a conference.  So, without the fancy diagram, your entities would be something like this...

```
Users
    Id

Roles
    Id

Conferences
    Id

UserRoles
    UserId
    RoleId

ConferenceUserRoles
    ConferenceId
    UserId
    RoleId
```

You may need to add a "UserRoleId" to UserRoles and use that in ConferenceUserRoles.  I'm not exactly sure how EF will handle the three-way relation table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help @Aaron Palmer. Please, see the new diagram to see if it agrees with what you said...